# UK EEA Family permit refused twice

Tags: united-kingdom

Me and my partner (Greek citizen) decided to apply for a EEA Family Permit but unfortunately were refused two times so far. And now we are looking for somone  to help us to resolve this issue.

As I’ve already mentioned my EEA FAMILY PERMIT APPLICATION (as an unmarried partner) was refused two times in the last two months (first application submitted on 09 May 2016, refusal on: 25 May 2016 – second application submitted on 17 June 2016, refusal on: 6 July 2016).

When my first application was refused I decided to apply for a second time with adding more evidence of relationship with my unmarried partner (EU citizen) - we added more descriptions in our letters, a testimony letter from my sister saying that this a genuine relationship and we added more private Facebook and WhatsApp conversations and photos of both of us from our travels around Europe in the last 4 years.).

According to the second refusal we failed to give a proof of cohabitation for at least two years. The Clearance Officer also stated that the office attempted to contact my sponsor without success on the mobile number I provided with my application, but that was because she was travelling outside the UK. They left 2 voice messages saying that they will contact her again but that never happened.

Nowt I have some questions that I am concerned about:

1. Is there any other visa type that can help me to get with my partner?
2. Will lawyer assistance guarantee me to get this Visa? How high the chances are?
3. What are the fees for this kind of assistance?
4. Is it better for me to make a new application or to appeal for the second one (appeal for eea family permit)?
5. How possible is it to prove the cohabitation with my partner since I work in Morocco and my partner works in the UK and I can’t leave my job and go and stay together for two years?

Comment: The refusal letter will have mentioned some specific bits of regulation. Can you please post either that, or even better the refusal letter with personal details blacked out?

Comment: It sounds like you have not in fact lived together for 2 years.  It will therefore be impossible to prove that you have lived together for 2 years.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, very helpful! Of course we met each other, we just didn't have a chance to live together. And all the worries we have now is because we were badly advised in the UK, so we started doubt our chances. Unfortunately, no solicitor here in the UK gives all the details. All our awareness is caused by a fear of all that processing affecting our union. (from eea partner)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other visa type that can help me to get with my partner?

At the moment, the EU does not offer anything like an unmarried partner permit. The UK is very strict with their version. So unless you wish to enter via means that is not related or dependent on your partner, no.

> Will lawyer assistance guarantee me to get this Visa?

Nothing guarantees any UK visa, certainly not a lawyer. Every case is judged on its own merit.

> How possible is it to prove the cohabitation with my partner since I work in Morocco and my partner works in the UK and I can’t leave my job and go and stay together for two years?

You cannot prove cohabitation since you are not actually cohabiting. Hence you do not qualify for this particular visa. The UK is very conservative on their interpretation of the phrase 'akin to marriage'. And their interpretation is not likely to change anytime soon for any reason at all.

Comment: thank you for ur feedback ...ok ! so as my partner gonna visit me in morocco next month we are planning to get married by the end of agust ! what should we take as a next step ?

Comment: As long as that is a legally binding marriage by Morocco law, it will be recognized by the UK. You can then apply for the permit, but I should warn that the permit is meant for those who intend on living in the UK permanently. It is not a multi-visit visa. Considering your previous applications, and what you've stated here, this point may come up.

Comment: We are also aware that an application for EEA Family Permit soon right after our marriage may cause a suspicion of a 'sham marriage'. What kind of evidence can show a real intention to live together permanently? E.g. money savings, etc.... and Will it help to describe our relationship from the very start again?

Comment: "We are also aware that an application for EEA Family Permit soon right after our marriage may cause a suspicion of a 'sham marriage'."
Not at all. In fact I would bet that most EEA Family Permits based on genuine marriages are very shortly thereafter the event.

Comment: "What kind of evidence can show a real intention to live together permanently?" I hope I don't sound too caustic, but would you consider actually living together? You are getting married so....

Comment: "Will it help to describe our relationship from the very start again?" I'm not sure what you mean by this question. Are you saying that your circumstances are so particularly special that the UK would consider your case differently than the many thousands of other similar cases they've seen? Have you two actually met?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, very helpful! Of course we met each other, we just didn't have a chance to live together. And all the worries we have now is because we were badly advised in the UK, so we started doubt our chances.

Unfortunately, no solicitor here in the UK gives all the details.

All our awareness is caused by a fear of all that processing affecting our union.

(from eea partner

Comment: @EEA Partner, Would you be able and willing to go live with your spouse for a couple of years? That makes a lot of things easier as far as your immigration future is concerned. The UK may be out of the picture at that point if/when you decide to leave Morocco. But most of the EU and certainly your home country would be very viable options (and Greece already is perhaps).

Comment: @KARIMOSILVER "It is not a multi-visit visa": That's not true. The permit may be issued for permanent relocation as well as for temporary visits. Also, the UK does have a well established history of being very quick to suspect marriages of convenience. There have been cases where they've done this for couples who were married for years and *had children together.*

Comment: I should have stated that the expectation for a residence permit is that the applicant be 'resident'. Permanent is not accurate, but I couldn't edit afterwords. The UK certainly has that history of suspicion, as well they should. And Morocco draws special ire. But the statement that an application shortly after marriage draws suspicion is not logical. Most recently married couples want/expect to physically be together immediately and forever after. I would bet that the overwhelming majority of EEA family spouse permit cases are genuine marriages. Some are not, no doubt, hence the suspicion.

Comment: But the ECO can and will expect evidence of a genuine marriage if marriage of convenience is suspected. And recent marriage is one of the grounds for such a suspicion. The EEA family permit is not a residence permit. There is no requirement or expectation that an applicant intend to reside in the UK.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the feedback but what are these evidences beside photos from the ceremony and convesations betwen us planing to get married ? is there any other evidence that you can mention ?

Comment: @KARIMOSILVER joint finances would be another bit of evidence -- if they exist.  For example, you might have shared costs for some expensive item like holiday travel.  But do not try to make it look like you have joint finances if you don't.  Don't try to falsify anything.  They are much more adept at idenfying fraud than you are at committing it.  Your photos and communications records could be enough. Joint financial information could help, but it is not necessarily required.